# Unable to plot line plot in for loop

Tags: python, plot, line

I have a simple code to plot dots with connecting line that works, but it failed to show connecting line when putting in a for loop, as in the code below. Thanks for help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Plot dots with connecting line OK
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y=x**2
plt.plot(x,y,'ro-')
plt.pause(0.5)
plt.close()

#Plot dots OK but no connecting line as expected
for x in range(10):
    y=x**2
    plt.plot(x,y,'ro-')
    plt.pause(0.5)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Your code plot 10 different charts with a dot in x=x and Y=x**2. If you want to do an animation check out Matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Comment: Look like the question is more complicated than it appears to be, as I have gotten no answer to it since I posted.